# `json.Marshal()` converts an array field of a struct to map which it shouldn't

Tags: json, go, docker-compose

I want to serialize object of `types.Project` from [github.com/compose-spec](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-go) into JSON

However, a field of ths struct which is supposed to be array, is always serialized into map.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"

    types "github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/types"
)

func main() {
    out := types.Project{
        Name: "foo",
        Services: []types.ServiceConfig{ // <- notice this field is an array
            {
                Name:  "bar",
                Image: "hello-world",
            },
        },
    }

    buf, err := json.Marshal(out)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    println(string(buf)) // <- notice the Services field now a map, which is incorrect!

    var in types.Project
    if err := json.Unmarshal(buf, &in); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

The code fails to run:

```
{"name":"foo","services":{"bar":{"command":null,"entrypoint":null,"image":"hello-world"}}}
panic: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Project.services of type types.Services

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox1081064727/prog.go:29 +0x168
```

The `out` object is serialized as

```json
{
    "name": "foo",
    "services": {
        "bar": {
            "command": null,
            "entrypoint": null,
            "image": "hello-world"
        }
    }
}
```

which should really be something like

```json
{
    "name": "foo",
    "services": [
        {
            "name": "bar",
            "command": null,
            "entrypoint": null,
            "image": "hello-world"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you're seeing is correct with respect to the [compose file specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#services-top-level-element), which says:

> A Compose file MUST declare a services root element as a map whose keys are string representations of service names, and whose values are service definitions.

The transformation of the list to a map is implemented by the [custom marshalers in `compose-go/types.go`](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/blob/9936908bc687edd9399db9276214ce3dfbe96a95/types/types.go#L69):

```golang
// MarshalYAML makes Services implement yaml.Marshaller
func (s Services) MarshalYAML() (interface{}, error) {
    services := map[string]ServiceConfig{}
    for _, service := range s {
        services[service.Name] = service
    }
    return services, nil
}

// MarshalJSON makes Services implement json.Marshaler
func (s Services) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    data, err := s.MarshalYAML()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return json.MarshalIndent(data, "", "  ")
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest how should a 3rd party code pass this `types.Project` object as JSON? (e.g. HTTP API calls)

Comment: The JSON you show in your question seems completely appropriate.

Comment: I am not sure if you fully understand the issue - the current `types. Project` struct does not support marshal/unmarshal round trip. The failure from the code clearly demonstrates the issue.